# How to filter out nested elements from a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following list of dictionaries:

```
messages_all = [{'type': 'message',
      'subtype': 'bot_message',
      'text': "This content can't be displayed.",
      'ts': '1573358255.000100',
      'username': 'Userform',
      'icons': {'image_30': 'www.example.com'},
      'bot_id': 'JOD4K22SJW',
      'blocks': [{'type': 'section',
        'block_id': 'yCKUB',
        'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
         'text': 'Your *survey* has a new response.',
         'verbatim': False}},
       {'type': 'section',
        'block_id': '37Mt4',
        'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
         'text': '*Thanks for your response. Where did you first hear about us?*\nFriend',
         'verbatim': False}},
       {'type': 'section',
        'block_id': 'hqps2',
        'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
         'text': '*How would you rate your experience?*\n9',
         'verbatim': False}},
       {'type': 'section',
        'block_id': 'rvi',
        'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn', 'text': '*city*\nNew York', 'verbatim': False}},
       {'type': 'section',
        'block_id': 'q=L+',
        'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
         'text': '*order_id*\n123456',
         'verbatim': False}},
       {'type': 'section',
        'block_id': 'iI6v',
        'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
         'text': '*user_id*\n987654',
         'verbatim': False}},
       {'type': 'section',
        'block_id': 'qfaZM',
        'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
         'text': '*user_name*\nJohn Smith',
         'verbatim': False}},
       {'type': 'section',
        'block_id': 'MkFq',
        'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
         'text': '*order_id*\n12345',
         'verbatim': False}},
       {'type': 'section',
        'block_id': '+zD',
        'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn', 'text': '*rating*\n9', 'verbatim': False}},
       {'type': 'section',
        'block_id': 'glVN',
        'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
         'text': '*office*\nSouth',
         'verbatim': False}},
       {'type': 'section',
        'block_id': 'Ox5',
        'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
         'text': '*date*\nJuly 1, 2020',
         'verbatim': False}},
       {'type': 'section',
        'block_id': 'pOZ',
        'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
         'text': '*ord_time*\n5:36PM',
         'verbatim': False}},
       {'type': 'section',
        'block_id': 'e1hbI',
        'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn',
         'text': '*sales*\nJ73',
         'verbatim': False}},
       {'type': 'actions',
        'block_id': '1Ug0A',
        'elements': [{'type': 'button',
          'action_id': '=iuO',
          'text': {'type': 'plain_text', 'text': 'View typeform', 'emoji': True},
          'url': 'www.example.com'}]},
       {'type': 'section',
        'block_id': 'Echk',
        'text': {'type': 'mrkdwn', 'text': ' ', 'verbatim': False}}]},
     {'client_msg_id': '123456jk-a19c-97fe-35c9-3c9f643cae19',
      'type': 'message',
      'text': '<@ABC973RJD>',
      'user': 'UM1927AJG',
      'ts': '1573323860.000300',
      'team': 'B09AJR39A',
      'reactions': [{'name': '+1', 'users': ['UM1927AJG'], 'count': 1}]}]
```

I'd like to be able to search through this list and filter out of the following dictionary:

```
 {'client_msg_id': '123456jk-a19c-97fe-35c9-3c9f643cae19',
  'type': 'message',
  'text': '<@ABC973RJD>',
  'user': 'UM1927AJG',
  'ts': '1573323860.000300',
  'team': 'B09AJR39A',
  'reactions': [{'name': '+1', 'users': ['UM1927AJG'], 'count': 1}]}
```

To do so, I have tried the following list comprehension:

```
filtered = [elem for elem in messages_all if not (elem.get('type') == 'message' and elem.get('subtype') == 'channel_join') 
                     and not (elem.get('type') == 'message' and elem.get('subtype') == 'channel_leave')
                     and not (elem.get('type') == 'message' and elem.get('reply_users_count') == 2)
                     and not (elem.get('type') == 'message' and elem.get('reactions') is not None) ]
```

Unfortunately, the `and not (elem.get('type') == 'message' and elem.get('reactions') is not None` is not dropping the dictionary above.

Would someone kindly help me with the syntax?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain in words what you're trying to filter? For example, what message types/subtypes do you want to keep vs delete?

Comment: I want to keep everything except that last block starting with `client_msg_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the last dictionary is the only one that has the "client_msg_id" key, you could use:

```
>>> [m for m in messages_all if not m.get('client_msg_id')]
```